# Smoke simulation "Bake" is missing (or moved?) from 2.8.0 to 2.8.2

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm trying to do a Smoke simulation following the various tutorial videos I've found, and could do it in 2.8.0 (after figuring out I needed to delete a BSDF texture on the Smoke Domain), but since upgrading to 2.8.2, a lot of the settings have moved and/or changed names.

Most importantly, the "Bake" command is missing in 2.8.2 (or at least moved from where it was in the Physics:Cache menu in 2.8.0). I found a "Bake Animation" command in the Object:Animation menu, but this doesn't seem to do what I need. When I render, it is always the same frame (somewhere in the middle of the animation).

See attached images for menu differences.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: 2.8.0 "Bake"]

[image: 2.8.2 no "Bake"]

Answer (score 4):

It's now under Settings : Bake Data / Free Data.

Blender 2.82 use a brand new simulation engine (Mantaflow) for fluids and smoke, so any tutorial prior to this version is outdated.

For the given screenshot *Cache > Type* change to *Final* then the *Bake* option appears below.

Comment: Hi thibsert, Thanks for the reply. Sorry for the newbie question, but I can't find "Settings"... you don't mean "preferences" do you? (I didn't see anything there either). Should I be able to see it when in Layout mode?

Comment: Ahh- never mind- I found it. Thanks again.

Comment: In your second screenshot you've got "Noise", "Guides" etc. In that same panel, "Settings" should be the first one.

Comment: @Ari If you ask something on forum and found solution, you could write where you have found this...
Someone shared knowledge with you so it is not well maniered to write "I found it".

Answer (score 4):

You need to change cache type for Modular or Final.
In case of:

Modular - Bake button appears in settings

Final - Bake button appears in Cache tab (still under Physics)

Modular:

[image: Modular]

Final:

[image: Final]

Comment: It is now named 'All'.